# Not all state attributes populating from firebase databse in react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been following a react tutorial by Wes Bos and I can't seem to get some of the state to persist using the firebase database. My 'order' state seems to persist, but the 'fishes' state in my inventory doesn't.

Specifically, I can see the changes made to 'fishes' once I change them in the react app, but if I exit the store and come back in, the order persists but the 'fishes' do not.

base.js

```
import Rebase from 're-base';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXXXXX",
  databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
});

const base = Rebase.createClass(app.database());

export default base;
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import Order from './Order';
import Inventory from './Inventory';
import Fish from './Fish';
import sampleFishes from '../sample-fishes';
import base from '../base';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.addFish = this.addFish.bind(this);
    this.loadSamples = this.loadSamples.bind(this);
    this.addToOrder = this.addToOrder.bind(this);
    this.updateFish = this.updateFish.bind(this);
    this.removeFish = this.removeFish.bind(this);
    this.removeFromOrder = this.removeFromOrder.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      fishes: {},
      order: {},
    };

  }

componentDidMount() {
    this.FishRef = base.syncState(`${this.props.match.params.storeId}/fishes`,
    {
      context: this,
      state: 'fishes' 
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.OrderRef = base.syncState(`${this.props.match.params.storeId}/order`,
    {
      context: this,
      state: 'order' 
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    base.removeBinding(this.FishRef);
    base.removeBinding(this.OrderRef);
  }

  addFish(fish) {
    const fishes = {...this.state.fishes};
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    fishes[`fish-${timestamp}`] = fish;
    this.setState({ fishes });
  }

  removeFish(key) {
    const fishes = {...this.state.fishes};
    fishes[key] = null;
    this.setState({ fishes });
  }

  updateFish(key, updatedFish) {
    const fishes = {...this.state.fishes};
    fishes[key] = updatedFish;
    this.setState({ fishes });
  }

  loadSamples() {
    this.setState({
      fishes: sampleFishes
    });
  }

  addToOrder(key) {
    const order = {...this.state.order};
    order[key] = order[key] + 1 || 1;
    this.setState({ order });
  }

  removeFromOrder(key){
    const order = {...this.state.order};
    delete order[key];
    this.setState({ order });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="catch-of-the-day">
        <div className="menu">
          <Header tagline="Fresh seafood market"/>
          <ul className="list-of-fishes">
            {Object
              .keys(this.state.fishes)
              .map(key => <Fish key={key}
                details={this.state.fishes[key]}
                addToOrder={this.addToOrder}
                index={key}
                />)
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
        <Order fishes={this.state.fishes}
          order={this.state.order}
          removeFromOrder={this.removeFromOrder}/>
        <Inventory addFish={this.addFish}
          loadSamples={this.loadSamples}
          fishes = {this.state.fishes}
          updateFish = {this.updateFish}
          removeFish = {this.removeFish}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you declared `componentDidMount` twice , here :

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.FishRef = base.syncState(`${this.props.match.params.storeId}/fishes`,
    {
      context: this,
      state: 'fishes' 
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.OrderRef = base.syncState(`${this.props.match.params.storeId}/order`,
    {
      context: this,
      state: 'order' 
    });
}
```

this mean the first will execute and the second will not or the other way around .

**fix** this by add the body of second the body of the first like this :

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.FishRef = base.syncState(`${this.props.match.params.storeId}/fishes`,
    {
      context: this,
      state: 'fishes' 
    });

    this.OrderRef = base.syncState(`${this.props.match.params.storeId}/order`,
    {
        context: this,
        state: 'order' 
    });

}
```

Comment: I feel pretty stupid right now. I was looking through tutorials to try and find how to mount multiple state properties but they all only gave examples with one property. This makes sense. Thanks

Comment: happy to help you :)